# Use factory to ensure a single instance behavior

Tags: php, singleton, factory

In PHP i am using a client which is connecting to a port and listening to it for all the time (using a while loop). If a message arrives, a callback function is called.
The problem is that you can only set one callback function per client. To have not dozens of clients with each listening to only one subscriber, i want to capsulate the client into another class which is holding one general callback function. This function will dispatch the incoming messages to the corresponding subscribers.

In my used framework, the factory pattern is also used.

I am wondering if its ok / clean to use the factory to ensure that only one client instance is created. And when yes, how to do this?

In the current implementation there is something like

```
private function getClient() {
    if(static::$client == null) 
    {
        static::$client = new Client();
    }
    return static::$client
}
```

but i think, this is a bad design due to the high dependency in the getClient() method (its not interchangeable anymore).

The second problem is, that if i create another encapsulating class (in which the client is defined) i'll always overwrite the callback function.

How is it possible to ensure, that only one encapsulating class instance with only one client is running to proper dispatch all registered subscribers? Is this a task for the factory? Any other approaches?

Thanks